# Multiple lines within parentheses

Tags: ruby

The following multi-line conditional statement returns unexpected result.

```
if (false and
false and
false
true)
  puts 123
end
# => 123
```

Notice the missing condition. Wondering why ruby interpreter did not detect the syntax problem in the condition.

Comment: "unexpected result" is subjective unless  you state what you expect and what you actually got.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### There is no syntax error there.

The newline character started a new expression, exactly the same way semicolon (`;`) does it.

```
(false and false and false; true)
# => true
```

This operator is like the [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) found in C and C++.

> a binary operator that evaluates its first operand and discards the result, and then evaluates the second operand and returns this value

...and similar to a [`do`-form in Clojure](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/do):

> Evaluates the expressions in order and returns the value of the last.

Comment: understood, but why by default new line expression in this condition is interpreting as 'OR' makes it valid expression?

Comment: It's not `or`. `;` (and equivalents) **always** returns the value of its "right" operand, evaluating both.

Comment: +1. Picky, perhaps, but "pretty much" is vague. How about "just as" or "equivalenly". I also think you should incorporate your comment in your answer.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I wasn't sure at the time of writing it's **exactly** the same. Double-checking never hurts. :)

Answer (score 3):

Statements in separate lines are evaluated separately. Simply, your last line in the parentheses (i.e., `true`) is returned.